# Alternate ways in place of zip

Tags: python, zip, tuples, alternate

I have below inputs,

```
inp = 'Sample'
n = 5
```

I would like to generate a list of tuples of `n` elements packing `input` with index. So that my output is,

```
[('Sample', 0), ('Sample', 1), ('Sample', 2), ('Sample', 3), ('Sample', 4)]
```

Below snippet does the work neat,

```
output = zip([inp]*n, range(n))
```

Just curious about alternate approaches to solve the same?

Comment: `[('Sample', x) for x in range(n)]`

Comment: Ah!!! That's really simple and neat than with `zip` ! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious solution (a list comprehension) has already been [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885839/alternate-ways-in-place-of-zip/47885915#comment82737248_47885839), so here's an alternative with [*`itertools.zip_longest`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), just for fun -

```
from itertools import zip_longest

r = list(zip_longest([], range(n), fillvalue=inp))
print(r)
[('Sample', 0), ('Sample', 1), ('Sample', 2), ('Sample', 3), ('Sample', 4)]
```

On python2.x, you'd need *`izip_longest`* instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
inp='sample'
n=5
print [(inp,i) for i in range(n)]
```

it Shows O/P as:

> > > > [('sample', 0), ('sample', 1), ('sample', 2), ('sample', 3), ('sample', 4)]

Comment: list comprehension is good way to solve the problem over zip function?